# How to use espeak command in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, voice-recognition, espeak

I would like to know how to use this command , and what is its benefits for a user .

I know its for speech and can read documents , but how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

**espeak** command :

a speech synthesizer for English (and several other languages) which will convert text to speech.

espeak options :

```
man espeak
```

For example to read the content of man pages :

```
man ls | espeak 



espeak --voices
```

List all available voice languages

```
espeak -v en-uk
```

use “en-uk” – British english to translate the text to speech.

change to your language

```
espeak -s
```

The default is 160 words per minute. You can reduce it using option -s

```
espeak --stdout -t file.txt | aplay


This will convert the text from the file.txt to speech.
```

Reference : [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/espeak-speech-synthesizer-for-ubuntu/#more-3120)